# Logic: Rank of Terms of a language

Tags: logic

In the book "A Course on Mathematical Logic" by S.M. Srivastava the rank of terms is defined as follows:

> Variables and constant symbols are terms of rank $0$; if $t_1,...,t_n$ are terms of rank $\le k$, and if $f_j$ is an $n$-ary function symbol, then $f_jt_1\ldots t_n$ is a term of rank at most $k+1$. Thus, the rank of a term $t$ is the smallest natural number $k$ such that $t$ is of rank $\le$ k.

I now wanted to show that the rank of the term $t = fcd$ ($c$,$d$ constants, $f$ a binary function) is $1$. It is obvious that $t$ is of rank $\le 1$. But it could still be of rank $\le 0$.

So my question is, should the first "if" in the above definition really be an "iff"?

Comment: It is quite common in **definitions** to use "if" as meaning "iff." For example, one might define *Abelian* by saying "A group $G$ is Abelian if for all $a$ and $b$ $\dots$."

Answer (score 4):

It does seem as though the author is somewhat imprecise in the formulation of *rank*, since (as you have noticed) it is not clear that *only* variables and constant symbols have rank $0$.  Perhaps the following definitions are more explicit, and are keeping with the author's intentions:

> - A term has "rank $\leq 0$" if it is either a variable or a constant symbol.
> - A term has "rank $\leq k+1$" if either it has rank $\leq k$ or it is of the form $f t_1 \ldots t_n$ where $f$ is an $n$-ary function symbol and $t_1 , \ldots , t_n$ are terms each with rank $\leq k$.
> - The *rank* of a term is the smallest natural number $k$ such that the term has rank $\leq k$.